# extract values from a list that falls in intervals specified by pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have a huge list of length 103237. And I have a data frame of shape (8173,6). I want to extract those values from list that fall between values specified by two columns (**1 AND 2**) in pandas dataframe. For example:

```
lst = [182,73,137,1,938]

###dataframe

0       1     2      3    4
John   150   183    NY    US
Peter   30   50     SE    US
Stef   900   969    NY    US
```

Expected output list:

```
lst = [182,938]
```

Since 182 falls between 150 and 183 of first row of dataframe and 938 falls between 900 and 969 of row 3 therefore the I want new list to have 182 and 938 from original list. In order to solve this problem I converted my dataframe to numpy array:

```
nn = df.values()

new_list = []
for item in lst:
    for i in range(nn.shape[0]):
        if item >= nn[i][1] and item <= nn[i][2]:
            new_list.append(item)
```

But above mentioned code take a long time since its O(n^2) and it doesn't scale well to my list which has 103237 items. How can do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the list and compare each element with all pairs of column 1 and 2 to see if there is any pair that would include the element.

```
[e for e in lst if (df['1'].lt(e) & df['2'].gt(e)).any()]
```

I did a test with 110000 elements in the list and 9000 rows in the dataframe and the code takes 32s to run on a macbook pro.

Comment: What will be the time complexity of this code? Can you briefly explain what you did here? Thanks!

Comment: Just added some notes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following: Assuming you have a value `item`, you can ask if in inside any interval by the following line

`((df[1] <= item) & (df[2] >= item)).any()`

the statements `(df[1] <= item)` and `(df[2] >= item)` return an boolean array of true/false. The '&' will return a single boolean array whether `item` is in specific interval. The add of `any()` in the end returns true if there is any True value in the boolean array, aka if there is an interval which is "True" (the number is inside the interval).

So for the a single item, you can get an answer by the above line.

To scan over all items you can the following:

```py
new_list = []
for item in lst:
    if ((df[1] <= item) & (df[2] >= item)).any():
        new_list.append(item)
```

or with list comperhension:

```py
new_list = [item for item in lst if ((df[1] <= item) & (df[2] >= item)).any()]
```

Edit: if this code is too slowly you can accelerate if even further with numba, but I believe using pandas vectorization (aka using `df[1]<=item` is good enough)

Comment: Thanks @Roim. This helps. I wasn't aware of Numba.